# Go Routine: Shared Global variable in web server

Tags: go

I have go web server running on port and handling post request which internally calls different url to fetch response using goroutine and proceed.

I have divided the whole flow to different method. Draft of the code.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

var status_codes string

func main() {

    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    /*router := NewRouter()*/
    router.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        _, _ = fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello!!!")
    })

    router.HandleFunc("/{name}", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        vars := mux.Vars(r)
        prepare(w, r, vars["name"])

    }).Methods("POST")

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", 8080), router))

}

func prepare(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, name string) {
    //initializing for the current request, need to maintain this variable for each request coming
    status_codes = ""

    //other part of the code and call to goroutine
    var urls []string
    //lets say all the url loaded, call the go routine func and wait for channel to respond and then proceed with the response of all url
    results := callUrls(urls)
    process(w, results)

}

type Response struct {
    status          int
    url             string
    body            string
}

func callUrls(urls []string) []*Response {
    ch := make(chan *Response, len(urls))
    for _, url := range urls {
        go func(url string) {
            //http post on url,
            //base on status code of url call, add to status code
            //some thing like

            req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(somePostData))
            req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
            req.Close = true

            client := &http.Client{
                Timeout: time.Duration(time.Duration(100) * time.Second),
            }

            response, err := client.Do(req)

            if err != nil {
                status_codes += "200,"
                //do other thing with the response received
            } else {
                status_codes += "500,"

            }

            // return to channel accordingly
            ch <- &Response{200, "url", "response body"}

        }(url)
    }
    var results []*Response
    for {
        select {
        case r := <-ch:
            results = append(results, r)
            if len(results) == len(urls) {
                //Done
                close(ch)
                return results
            }

        }
    }
}

func process(w http.ResponseWriter, results []*Response){
    //read those status code received from all urls call for the given request
    fmt.Println("status", status_codes)

    //Now the above line keep getting status code from other request as well
    //for eg. if I have called 5 urls then it should have
    //200,500,204,404,200,

    //but instead it is 
    //200,500,204,404,200,204,404,200,204,404,200, and some more keep growing with time
}
```

The above code does:

1. Variable declare globally, Initialized in prepare function.
2. append value in go routine callUrls function
3. read those variable in process function

Now should I pass those variable declared globally to each function call to make them local as it won't be shared then?(I would hate to do this.)

Or is there any other approach to achieve the same thing without adding more argument to function being called.

As I will have few other string and int value as well that will be used across the program and in go routine function as well.

What will be the correct way of making them thread safe and only 5 codes for each request coming on port simultaneously.

Comment: "Now should I pass those variable declared globally to each function call to make them local as it won't be shared then?" - this, combined with the `+=` would indeed make changes local (and meaningless).

Comment: If you modify global state, you need some synchronization around it (mutexes and the like)

Comment: I mean by passing it to each function is something like 
in prepare function
```status_codes := ""
results := callUrls(urls, status_codes)
process(w, results, status_codes ])```
So by this an empty variable will be appened in callUrls and after that it can be used in process function. But as said i would not like to do this.I came across Context not sure if thats the thing i need to use.

Comment: "and after that it can be used in process function" - it can, but it'll still be empty.

Comment: So what would be the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use global variables, be explicit instead and use function arguments. Moreover, you have a race condition on `status_codes` because it is accessed by multiple goroutines without any mutex lock.

Take a look at my fix below.

```
func prepare(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, name string) {
    var urls []string
    //status_codes is populated by callUris(), so let it return the slice with values
    results, status_codes := callUrls(urls)
    //process() needs status_codes in order to work, so pass the variable explicitely
    process(w, results, status_codes)

}

type Response struct {
    status int
    url    string
    body   string
}

func callUrls(urls []string) []*Response {
    ch := make(chan *Response, len(urls))
    //In order to avoid race condition, let's use a channel
    statusChan := make(chan string, len(urls))
    for _, url := range urls {
        go func(url string) {
            //http post on url,
            //base on status code of url call, add to status code
            //some thing like

            req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(somePostData))
            req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
            req.Close = true

            client := &http.Client{
                Timeout: time.Duration(time.Duration(100) * time.Second),
            }

            response, err := client.Do(req)

            if err != nil {
                statusChan <- "200"
                //do other thing with the response received
            } else {
                statusChan <- "500"

            }

            // return to channel accordingly
            ch <- &Response{200, "url", "response body"}

        }(url)
    }
    var results []*Response
    var status_codes []string
    for !doneRes || !doneStatus { //continue until both slices are filled with values
        select {
        case r := <-ch:
            results = append(results, r)
            if len(results) == len(urls) {
                //Done
                close(ch)      //Not really needed here
                doneRes = true //we are done with results, set the corresponding flag

            }
        case status := <-statusChan:
            status_codes = append(status_codes, status)
            if len(status_codes) == len(urls) {
                //Done
                close(statusChan) //Not really needed here
                doneStatus = true //we are done with statusChan, set the corresponding flag
            }
        }

    }
    return results, status_codes
}

func process(w http.ResponseWriter, results []*Response, status_codes []string) {
    fmt.Println("status", status_codes)
}
```

Comment: I did tried mutex.lock and defer Unlock function for map but after some request, I saw process stuck at point may be because of Unlock not called, Anyway. So coming on above changes I have to pass more argument to write to other variable I may need? What about if need to read few values from request body, that should as well be passed as argument so that no other request override those values?

Comment: Correct. Global variables are definitely not the way to go. If a function needs more data in order to perform its job, then just pass those data as explicit arguments. You can define a new `type struct` in order to pass them in a concise way.

Comment: using struct with 8-9 key/values is making app more memory consuming, any way to optimize the memory?Response struct also could be causing memory issue as there of atleast 10 url hitting out for each request and app has to serve thousands of req per sec.